# Как в Retrofit2 обработать JSON с полем в которое приходят разные типы данных

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, gson

Как в Retrofit обработать JSON с полем в которое приходят разные типы данных? (Уточнение: в ответе приходит много типизированных полей, но например, одно free_val не типизировано)
Например есть JSON responce

- вариант 1 {free_val:"any text"}
- вариант 2 {free_val:{p1:1, p2:2}}
- вариант 3 {free_val:{[1,2,3]}

**Как описать JSON так что бы всегда приходила строка даже если это массив или структура при этом {p1:1, p2:2} вернется как String "{p1:1, p2:2}"**

```
class MyModel{
    @SerializedName("free_val")
    @Expose
    //Может как-то можно указать, что это всегда строка?
    //чтобы получать {free_val:{p1:1, p2:2}} как "{p1:1, p2:2}"
    String freeVal;
// далее геттеры сеттер
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно заюзать `JsonDeserializer` прямо к нужному полю, что даст больше гибкости
Код на kotlin

```
class FreeValDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<String> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): String {
       return json.toString()
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyModel{
    @SerializedName("free_val")
    @Expose
    @JsonAdapter(FreeValDeserializer::class)
    var freeVal: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для таких случаев надо писать свой адаптер:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, new JsonDeserializer<MyModel>(){
    @Override
    public MyModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.freeVal = json.getAsJsonObject().get("freeVal").toString();
        // model.otherFields = json.getAsJsonObject().get("otherFields").getAs...
        return model;
    }
});
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            ...
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder.create()))
            .build();
```

Другой вариант, объявить `free_val` как `JsonElement` и работать с ним соответственно как с `JsonElement`'ом, проверяя `isJsonPrimitive` -> строка, число... `isJsonObject` -> объект и т.д.

ЗЫ Писал в окне редактора, могут быть ошибки в синтаксисе.